# Trying to convert C++ binary array to hexadecimal then print results

Tags: c++, function, binary, hex, decimal

I'm wanting to print an int array with 8 bytes and convert it to bin & hex with the output as such:

```
0 00000000 00
1 00000001 07
...
```

I've finished creating the binary convert function. I want to use the same function as the binary conversion -with an array, but check the left half with the right half and solve each different sided of the 8 bytes; left most -3 and right most is -7. 
What am I doing wrong? I cannot figure out how to implement it and I know my hex function is all out of wack.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

const int num = 8; //may not be needed -added for hex
void Generatebinary(int arr[]);
void GeneratehexDec(int arr[]);
void print_binary(int arr[]); //haven't created yet
int main()
{
    int arr[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 256)
    {
        Generatebinary(arr);
        print_binary(arr); //not created yet
        GeneratehexDec(arr);
        i++;
    }
}

void Generatebinary(int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 1)
            arr[i] = 0;
        else if (arr[i] == 0)
        {
            arr[i] = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void GereatehexDec(int num)
{ //improper use
    int a;
    int i;
    int answer[] = { };
    a = num % 16;
    i++;
    answer[i] = num;

    for (int i = num; i > 0; i--)
    {
        cout << answer[i];
    }
    cout << a;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: [Your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) wants to know how many bytes of storage `int answer[] = { };` allocated.

Comment: So, as far as I can tell, you are trying to store an 8-bit integer inside an 8 element integer array for some reason, and `Generatebinary()` increments the thing? Is `GeneratehexDec()` supposed to output the thing in hex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't do `int answer[] = { };` an array has to be pre-allocated (indicating how many elements it will store) or has to be dynamically allocated during run-time, then be freed, you have to manage your memory, not forget to deallocate... It's for this reason that [Stroustrup tells you to not use arrays unless necessary](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html). Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
void GereatehexDec(int num)
{ //improper use
    int a = 0; // always initialize your variables
    int i = 0; // is this i supposed to be the same as the i in the for loop below?
    std::vector<int> answer;
    a = num % 16;
    i++; // this doesn't make sense
    answer.at(i) = num;

    for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) // what about the i variable you declared previously?
    {
        cout << answer.at(i);
    }
    cout << a;
}
```

Here's a template function that could help you (converts numbers into string hex)

```
template <typename I> std::string n2hexstr(I w, size_t hex_len = sizeof(I) << 1) {
    static const char* digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    std::string rc(hex_len, '0');
    for (size_t i = 0, j = (hex_len - 1) * 4; i<hex_len; ++i, j -= 4)
        rc[i] = digits[(w >> j) & 0x0f];
    return "0x" + rc;
}

int main() {
std::cout << n2hexstr(127);
}
```